# How to combine array.h, array.cpp and main.cpp files together?

Tags: c++

How to combine array.h, array.cpp and main.cpp files together? I am getting an error while compiling main.cpp, that class Array is not declared in scope.

main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>


#include "Array.h" 
#include "Array.cpp"


using namespace std;

int main(){
    Array a;
    a.Array();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Array.h:

#ifndef ARRAY_H_INCLUDED
#define ARRAY_H_INCLUDED


    class Array{
    private:
        int data;// The value or data stored in the node
        int ArraySize;//Size of array
        int* array;

    public:
        Array();
};
#endif

Array.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


#include "Array.h" // user defined header file



Array::Array(){ //initialise array
    cout << "Initialising array elements----------------->"<< endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++){
        //array[i]= 1;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

ERROR message: invalid use of 'class Array'

Comment: There's not enough context here to answer your question. You need to [edit] your question to contain a **[mcve]**, but pay specific attention to **minimal**. Do not copy+paste all of your code into your question, only the the bare minimum to reproduce your error. Likely this means having array.h declare an empty class `Array`, and main.cpp including array.h and attempting to use `Array`

Comment: Try this: `g++ -o main.exe main.cpp array.cpp`

Comment: main.cpp should do `#include "array.h"`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you are attempting to call the constructor of a class on an instance of that class:

```
Array a;
a.Array();
```

When you declare a function the same name as a class, you are creating a constructor for that class.

```
class Array
{
    public:
    // Default constructor
    Array();
    // This is a function you can call
    void PrintData();
}
```

You can't *call* this function though. It's called automatically when you create an object of class `Array`:

```
Array a; // This will call Array's constructor
a.PrintData(); // This will call the function PrintData on the object 'a'
```